# Why do I need to group by columns that I don't need to group by?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a query like this:

```
                SELECT
                    car.id,
                    car.make,
                    car.model,
                    car.vin,
                    car.year,
                    car.color
                FROM car GROUP BY car.make
```

I want to group the result by make so I can eliminate any duplicate makes. I'm essentially trying to do a `SELECT DISTINCT`. But I get this error:

```
ERROR column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

It seems silly to group by each column when I dont want to see any of them in a group. How do I get around this?

Comment: If there are multiple rows for each `make` then which values of `model` or `vin` should the database pick? Postgres will not just return some random results to you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `GROUP BY`, use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.make) c.*
FROM car c
ORDER BY c.make;
```

This will return an arbitrary row for each make.  Which row?  An arbitrary one.  You can include a second key in the `ORDER BY` to determine the particular row you want (cheapest, oldest, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

All column names in SELECT list must appear in GROUP BY clause unless name is used only in an aggregate function. PostgreSQL only let you omit from the GROUP BY clause columns that are functionally dependent on columns that are in the GROUP BY.